# Does JavaScript in the browser support ByteArrays?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

The [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) class provides methods and properties to optimize reading, writing, and working with binary data.

How to use byte arrays [tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d54.html).

I'm looking for a very similar API as the one linked.

I'm looking for a class the browser provides not hack or workaround. The linked question does not provide the answer.

Comment: Hi Matt Ball. This not a duplicate. Please reopen. My question asks for an actual class and API.

Comment: Have a look http://www.javascripture.com/Uint8Array to see how JS typed arrays are used. There are not standard functions like AS3's read/writeObject or compress/uncompress but there are js frameworks that provide typed array wrappers for similar features...

Comment: @SushiHangover that's exactly the info i was looking for. thank you! i posted an edited version of this question over here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521944/does-javascript-support-a-bytearray-class-in-the-browser/34521997?noredirect=1#34521997. i'm going to delete this one since it was closed due to drive by moderation.

Comment: Was sent this link, https://gist.github.com/sunetos/275610#file-bytearray-js. It has the read methods but not the write methods. So close, yet so far. Maybe you could vote for it as well?

Comment: Ah.. that is from http://www.adamia.com/blog/high-performance-javascript-port-of-actionscript-byteArray FYI: James Ward wrote a AMF.js library using ideas from that... If you are looking
 for read/write objects from js typed byte arrays, you should look at the AMF javascript ports. There are a few floating around, just search for `AMF javascript`